# println dictionary has "Optional"

Tags: swift

Consider this snippet:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
println(interestingNumbers["Square"])

let individualScores = [75, 43, 103, 87, 12]
println(individualScores)
```

The console output:

Optional([1, 4, 9, 16, 25])

[75, 43, 103, 87, 12]

Why was there an "Optional" in the dictionary case?

Comment: The dictionary could have value for certain key or it could me empty. So, it is represented by Optional in swift. It should be easy since you know that the key has value, you could unwrap it directly as 
println(interestingNumbers["Square"]!)

Comment: What if you tried `interestingNumbers["Hello"]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift dictionaries are returning optionals for safety. If you try to access a key which does not exists that would give you nil.

> You can also use subscript syntax to retrieve a value from the dictionary for a particular key. Because it is possible to request a key for which no value exists, a dictionary’s subscript returns an optional value of the dictionary’s value type. If the dictionary contains a value for the requested key, the subscript returns an optional value containing the existing value for that key. Otherwise, the subscript returns nil

[From The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8)

and

> Use subscripting to access the individual elements in any dictionary.
>   The value returned from a dictionary's subscript is of type ValueType? — an optional with an underlying type of the dictionary’s ValueType

[From the Swift Standard Library Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, dictionaries return optionals because if you try to access a key that does not exist, it can return nil