# Accessing a tuple stored in a dictionary

Tags: swift

I am trying to access a elements of a tuple that is stored inside of a dictionary.

```
// declare the dictionary
var a: [Int: (start: Int, end: Int)]!
a=[
    0: (1, 2),
    3: (4, 5)
]

// printout is "Optional {(1, 2)}"
var c = a[0]
println(c)

// throws an error - "does not have a member"
c.start

// printout is also "Optional {(1, 2)}"
var b = a[0].0
println(b)
```

In the case above, c cannot access "start", while b is still a tuple.

What is my error here in trying to access the tuple in the dictionary?

Comment: `c` is optional. try `c?.start`.

Comment: In your case you've to use implicitly unwrapping '!' instead '?' to keep the result as non-optional.  The solution is c!.start; println("\(a[0]!.start)"), gives you the result.

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to tuples. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979969/println-dictionary-has-optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
// declare the dictionary
var a: [Int: (start: Int, end: Int)]!
a=[
    0: (1, 2),
    3: (4, 5)
]

// printout is "Optional {(1, 2)}"
var c = a[0]
println(c)

// just use ! to force unwrap your optional
c!.start

// or you can use if let to unwrap it
if let c = a[0] {
    println(c)
    c.start
}

var b = a[0].0
println(b!)
```

you can check if b is nil like this

```
if let b = b {
    println(b)  // here b is not optional anymore
}
```

Comment: thanks! what i do not understand/threw me off course is why var b will still be Optional{{1, 2}} even when it has the .0?

Comment: you var is not an optional when using if let.

Comment: i mean for the var b, the one at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

First you can't say

```
c.start
```

because `c` is optional, you would need to unwrap it like :

```
c!.start
```

the same thing for `b`, you can't do `b.0`, but you would need `b!.0`, which is the same bty as b!.start

nevertheless, you should be able to access `c` and `b` in the same way.