# NSDictionary returning an optional integer when retrieving information

Tags: swift, dictionary, int, type-conversion, nsdictionary

I have dictionary declared like this:

```
var friendLetterCount:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary: [String:Int]())
```

and I obviously want to retrieve the information for the keys in the Dictionary, but when I do it, it only returns optional integers, how do I make this so that they are integers only?

I retrieve like this:

```
friendLetterCount["a"]
```

and when I print it to the console it says

```
optional(1)
```

I've tried converting it in all the ways I can imagine, but it always gives me an error saying

```
'(NSObject, AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'Int'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979969/println-dictionary-has-optional (only with NSDictionary instead of Dictionary). – Optionals are a key concept of the Swift language, you  really should read the documentation and learn how to handle them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Optional(1)` value just means that the value is an optional swift type.

You can unwrap the value from an optional using the `!` operator.

```
let a = friendLetterCount["a"]! as Int
println(a)
```

`a` will the unwrapped value.

You can also use `optional binding` to check for nil while also doing unwrapping.

```
if let a = friendLetterCount["a"] as? Int
{
    println(a)
}
```

Please learn about Optionals from Apple's Swift Book.

Also you can read articles like this
http://www.appcoda.com/beginners-guide-optionals-swift/

Comment: Better use `as? Int` instead of  `as Int?`, otherwise it will crash if the value exists, but is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AppModel: NSObject {

private  var _user_id:String?

final func serviceResult(results:NSObject) {

var data = results as? NSDictionary
_user_id = String (data?.objectForKey("userId") as! Int)
 println("user id \(_user_id)")

}

}

Note: AppMOdel is a NSObject class, results is the parsed JSON DATA, data- NSDictionary, _user_id is a private variable.

It return the print as : 

user id Optional("8")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are not sure about the value is always Integer (Usually happens this with String/Intger),the safest way is :

```
if let count = friendLetterCount["a"]?.integerValue  {

}
```